# Get records from odoo relational table

Tags: python, relational-database, odoo

I have two models in my odoo project. Employee and equipment, as shown bellow.

Equipment/model.py

```py
    from openerp import models, fields, api
    import datetime
    
    
    class equipment(models.Model):
        _name = 'equipment.equipment'
    
        name = fields.Char(string='Name', )
        date_of_purchase = fields.Date(string='Date Of Purchase', default=fields.Date.today(), )
        write_off_days = fields.Integer(string="Days To Write-off", required=True, )
        write_off_date = fields.Date(string="Write-off Date", compute="_get_write_off_date", )
        price = fields.Float(string="Price '$'",  required=True, )
        description = fields.Char(string="Description", required=False, )
    
        employee_id = fields.Char(string="Owner", compute="_get_owner", )
    
        @api.one
        @api.depends('employee_id')
        def _get_owner(self):
            //result = self.env.['res.equipment_table'].
            //get id from relation database                        <-------------
    
        @api.one
        @api.depends('write_off_days', 'date_of_purchase')
        def _get_write_off_date(self):
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.date_of_purchase, "%Y-%m-%d")
            self.write_off_date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.write_off_days)
```

employee/model.py

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api


class employee(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.employee'

    name = fields.Char(string='First Name')
    last_name = fields.Char(string='Last Name')
    birth_date = fields.Date(string='Birth Date', default=fields.Date.today(), )

    equipment_ids = fields.Many2many(string="Equipment", comodel_name="equipment.equipment", relation="equipment_table", )

    total_equipment_price = fields.Float(string="Total Equipment Price '$'", compute="_get_total_equipment_price", )

    @api.one
    @api.depends('equipment_ids')
    def _get_total_equipment_price(self):
        total = 0
        for equipment in self.equipment_ids:
            total += equipment.price
        self.total_equipment_price = total
```

I have many2many field, which holds all equipment that employee owns. I need to update the equipment owner every time the field is changed. The reason for this is.. when a user adds new equipment to the employee, there should be shown only unowned equipment. That is why I need to check and update the owner.

I already made a domain to check if equipment already has an owner, which will be shown below. Just need to update that employee_id field somehow.

```
     <notebook>
         <page string="Equipment">
             <group>
                 <field name="equipment_ids" domain="[('employee_id', '=', False)]"/>
             </group>
         </page>
     </notebook>
```

Comment: You can change the type of `employee_id` to `Many2one` and override `create` and `write` methods in `employee.employee` model to set the ``employee_id`` field value using `equipment_ids` relation.

Comment: I tryed something like that, my problem is that I don't know how to use that relation

Comment: After calling `super`, loop over records to be able to use `record.equipment_ids.write({'employee_id': record.id})`

Comment: Can You please write down, how would that look like, I have no idea what are you talking about. Before 3 days, I didnt know that odoo exists.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `employee_id` to `Many2one`:

```
employee_id = fields.Many2one('employee.employee', string="Owner")
```

Override `create` and `write` methods to set `employee_id` each time new equipment is added to the list:

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.employee'

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        res = super(Employee, self).create(values)
        if res.equipment_ids:
            res.equipment_ids.write({'employee_id': res.id})
        return res

    @api.multi
    def write(self, values):
        res = super(Employee, self).write(values)
        for r in self:
            equipment_ids = r.equipment_ids.filtered(lambda s: not s.employee_id)
            if equipment_ids:
                equipment_ids.write({'employee_id': r.id})
        return res
```

Because an equipment can set to one owner, I suggest you to change the type of `equipment_ids` to `One2many` to be able to set a list of equipments by employee and the `employee_id` field value will be set automatically for you when you add equipment to the list.

If you change the value of `employee_id` the equipment will be automatically visible in the list of equipments of the new employee.

```
equipment_ids = fields.One2many("equipment.equipment", 'employee_id', string="Equipments")
```

***Reset owner***

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    removed_ids = set()
    old_ids = {r.id: r.equipment_ids.ids for r in self}
    res = super(Employee, self).write(values)
    for r in self:
        equipment_ids = r.equipment_ids.filtered(lambda s: not s.employee_id)
        if equipment_ids:
            equipment_ids.write({'employee_id': r.id})
        removed_ids |= set(old_ids[r.id]) - set(r.equipment_ids.ids)
    self.equipment_ids.browse(removed_ids).write({'employee_id': False})
    return res
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a single onchange method to update that field, instead of overriding those methods? Can't check if it is working, cause I can't make my server working. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023646/odoo-redirects-infinitely-on-server-startup) if You want.

Comment: I need that `equipment_ids` to bee `many2many` field because I need `many2many` functionality. I need a window with checkboxes when adding equipment to the list. If that field is `one2many`, it will open a window for creating new equipment.

Comment: It's working, but when I remove equipment from an employee, his owner field is not changed to empty.

Comment: You need to update the field value. Find out the removed equipments, then set the field value to `False`. I added a quick example, check my edit.