# Odoo redirects infinitely on server startup

Tags: python, server, odoo, werkzeug

A didn't change anything before the last server startup, and now suddenly I can't make it run properly. It keeps redirecting and loading modules when I open his webpage. After some time, the web browser writes this error:

On Goggle Chrome

```
This page isn’t working
0.0.0.0 redirected you too many times.
```

On Mozilla Firefox

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the 
request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

Here is the log from the server:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/odoo/odoo.py --addons-path=/opt/odoo/addons/,/home/josipmaricevic/Documents/Projects/PycharmProjects/custom_modules,/home/josipmaricevic/Documents/Projects/PycharmProjects/zadatak_v2_odoo
2021-06-17 16:32:55,006 7361 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0
2021-06-17 16:32:55,006 7361 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/josipmaricevic/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', u'/home/josipmaricevic/Documents/Projects/PycharmProjects/custom_modules', u'/home/josipmaricevic/Documents/Projects/PycharmProjects/zadatak_v2_odoo', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons']
2021-06-17 16:32:55,006 7361 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2021-06-17 16:32:55,006 7361 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2021-06-17 16:32:55,006 7361 INFO ? openerp: database user: josipmaricevic
2021-06-17 16:32:55,080 7361 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2021-06-17 16:33:08,627 7361 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2021-06-17 16:33:08,881 7361 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2021-06-17 16:33:08,968 7361 INFO ? openerp.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2021-06-17 16:33:08,979 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:08,985 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:08,996 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,031 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.03s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:09,242 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.http: Generating nondb routing
2021-06-17 16:33:09,255 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:09] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:09,266 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,271 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:09,282 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,289 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:09,552 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:09] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:09,562 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,568 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:09,579 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,586 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:09,790 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:09] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:09,802 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,808 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:09,819 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:09,826 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,035 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:10] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:10,048 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,053 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,063 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,071 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,277 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:10] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:10,289 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,295 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,305 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,313 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,508 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:10] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:10,520 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,527 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,538 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,547 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,742 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:10] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:10,755 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,761 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,772 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,780 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,972 7361 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2021 16:33:10] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2021-06-17 16:33:10,984 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:10,989 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2021-06-17 16:33:10,999 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2021-06-17 16:33:11,007 7361 INFO odoo_tech2 openerp.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
...
```

I have werkzeug version 0.9.6, as it is requested. Tried installing another and newer version, and didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved by reinstalling postgres and assigning the corresponding odoo user